# How strong is the Starship bottom bulkhead?

Tags: spacex-starship, thrust, pressure

I am wondering how much of a role does the pressurization of the propelant tanks play in making them withstand the engine thrust.

What I am getting at is how much would the pressure offset or balance out the thrust from the other side of the bottom bulkhead where the engines are mounted.

The wider concern is how important is the pressurization in regard to transferring engine thrust. That is how much thrust could the rocket structure take unpressurized - would it be 10% or 90%?

In the absence of data, info on other rockets is welcome, too.

Where the question comes from:

[image: Mk1 thrust puck and bottom bulkhead]

[image: SN4 bottom bulkhead at cry temperatures]

Comment: Tank pressure and acceleration caused by the engine thrust do not counteract. At the propellant pump inlet, the pressure is the sum of tank gas pressure and the pressure caused by the acceleration working on the fluid column.

Comment: Agreed. What I mean is regarding the bulkhead - how much does the pressurization help it not to collapse under the thrust of the engines.

Comment: Since the bottom dome is pretty thin, basically ALL of the engine thrust is counteracted by pressure in the tank.  (6 engines, or even 3 SL or 3Vaccum at at time X 400Klbs thrust means that 1.2 million lbs of thrust vs 4mm thick stainless steel, suggests that the strength of the dome is a rounding error).

Comment: The pressure at the bottom bulkhead is sum of the tank gas pressure and the pressure caused by the acceleration to the liquid column from surface down to the bulkhead. Again no counteract.

Comment: @geoffc metric please :-)

Comment: I like metric, but I think of thrust in lbs of thrust not Newtons.  Kg, m, Litre, Pascal are all awesome but Newtons are for figs!

Comment: @geoffc Do you assume that the engines are somehow mounted to the bottom of the tank? If so, which photo/sketch do you have in mind?

Comment: @Uwe Imagine the tanks were not pressurized and the engines were lit (disregarding that the pumps would probably not function without the pressure). What would happen to the bottom bulkhead? Say the engines could be started gradually 0 - 100%. At what point would the bulkhead give?

Comment: @PunchyRascal could you please provide us with the design drawft / photo that you base your question on? Even if Starship's design was clear at the moment (which it is not to me), future readers might have a hard time following the reasoning given here because the design is changing quickly.

Comment: The tank gas pressure could not be zero, at least the vapor pressure of the propellant is neccessary to store the liquid propellant.

Comment: Added some pictures illustrating what I am talking about. @Uwe Let's say the tanks are at ambient pressure give or take.